# ¿Puede un dropdownlist filtrarse de acuerdo a las letras que vaya introduciendo?

Tags: c#, jquery, sql-server, asp.net

Tengo el siguiente `DropDowList`

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropAgent" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Que lleno de la siguiente manera con `c#`

```
IList<mg1DAO> resultList = new List<mg1DAO>();
resultList = ObjConnectorAgent.findAll();
DropAgent.Items.Add(new ListItem("Seleccione una opción","0"));
DropAgent.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
DropAgent.DataSource = resultList;
DropAgent.DataTextField = "CNOMBREA01";
DropAgent.DataValueField = "CIDAGENTE";
DropAgent.DataBind();
```

Lo que quiero saber es si se puede convertir o existe la manera de que el `DropDownList` sea como un `input` en donde yo voy introduciendo una letra y este a su vez me va arrojando las coincidencias

Comment: Con librerías externas del lado cliente _JS_ , Sí es posible. Por ejemplo [Semantic](https://semantic-ui.com/collections/form.html#form)

Comment: Muy bien Gracias, probare Semantic y te platico bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución a mi pregunta, fue gracias a la ayuda de un `plugin` llamado `chosen`

Su utilización es demasiado sencilla, a continuación les dejo un ejemplo de lo que realice

Tengo el siguiente DropDowList

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropAgent" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Que lleno de la siguiente manera con c#

```
IList<mg1DAO> resultList = new List<mg1DAO>();
resultList = ObjConnectorAgent.findAll();
DropAgent.Items.Add(new ListItem("Seleccione una opción","0"));
DropAgent.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
DropAgent.DataSource = resultList;
DropAgent.DataTextField = "CNOMBREA01";
DropAgent.DataValueField = "CIDAGENTE";
DropAgent.DataBind();
```

Lo único que realice fue agregar la siguiente clase al control `asp DropDownList`

**CssClass="chosen-select form-control"**

Quedando el resultado de la siguiente manera

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropClientQuotation" runat="server" CssClass="chosen-select form-control">
```

Ademas de que también, tenemos que crear un archivo `js`, el cual sera el que nos ayude a iniciar el plugin. Con las siguientes lineas de código

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.chosen-select').chosen();
    $('.chosen-container').css('width', '100%');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar [select2](https://select2.github.io/) donde te costumiza tu select como un searchbox.

Ahi un ejemplo basado en el codigo que nos proveiste.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#<%= DropAgent.ClientId %>").select2()
});
```

Comment: Muy bien bro, Gracias probare la solución

Comment: @Miguel ¿Lograste hacer funcionar esto?

Comment: Que tal @fredyfx, si logre solucionarlo con una libreria llamada chosen

Comment: bien felizmente @Miguel, aquí revisando las preguntas que quedaron en el aire, te agradecería que compartas la solución a tu pregunta y luego la marques como resuelta (check verde) así ayudas a mantener la salud del sitio :D